# Which XML-tags describe actually the Contract of a web service in WSDL?

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, namespaces, wsdl

could somebody please explain, which tags of a WSDL document describe the contract of a web service?
example:

```
<definitions
    xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:abc="urn:abc"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"
    targetNamespace="urn:abc"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
>
```

I know that the xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" concerns about the SOAP Binding and xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" concerns about the HTTP GET POST requests, but i don't understand how to determine the contract of a web service. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The following post (Understanding  WSDL) might be helpful

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996486.aspx#understand_topic2